# Design pattern for UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, design-patterns

My app has a table view, for which the data used to fill it up were from remote service, the data is also expected to change on demand when user tap on a refresh button. Based on that, I am wondering what would be the best design pattern for the scenario, anyone can provide some suggestions or samples?

Comment: Try the stanford iOS course, the lecture on blocks and multithreading - this has a sample app which does exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MVC](http://maniacdev.com/2009/10/a-quick-explanation-of-mvc/)?

Edit (to try and be a bit more useful):

Model: your own class for this that communicates with the web-service and returns data to the controller as requested. You'll probably download the data and parse it into arrays depending upon how you want to sort/manipulate it.

View: your UI as either a .xib or written in code or a combination of .xib and code

Controller: the table view controller

I imagine most of the work will be in the model.

You could check out the LazyTableImages source code sample from Apple.

and

You should be able to get a prototype up and running pretty quickly using hard-coded data in arrays in the model, and then at a later date modify your model to retrieve real data from the web-service.

Comment: yeah, but for the UITableViewController and specifically for the datasource filled with data from remote web services, is there a sample that I can take a peek and learn from?